# Propositional logic without rules of inference and assumptions (except MP)

Tags: lo.logic, formal-languages

I was wondering whether it would be possible to do propositional logic without any rules of inference and assumptions (except modus ponens).

I have the following axioms:

1. $ p \to (q \to p) $
2. $ (p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r)) $
3. $ (\lnot p \to \lnot q) \to (q \to p) $
4. MP: From $ p $ and $ p \to q $, infer $ q $.

The other connectives ($ \lor $ and $ \land $) are defined like this:

$ p \lor q := \lnot p \to q $

$ p \land q := \lnot (p \to \lnot q) $

For example, [double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Proofs) uses [hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism): from $ p \to q $ and $ q \to r $, infer $ p \to r $.

Moreover, I can't find proofs for (or prove myself) common rules of inference in natural deduction, such as:

- $ (p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p) $
- $ p \to \lnot \lnot p $
- $ p \to (p \lor q) $
- $ (p \land q) \to p $
- $ ((p \to q) \land (q \to r)) \to (p \to r) $

My question is whether it is possible to not use rules of inference and assumptions (except MP) in propositional logic, or that you can't prove these statements without them.

I found this question, but it does not have any answers yet: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468217/prove-double-negation-introduction-without-elimination-in-a-propositional-logic

### Example proof

I hope this clarifies some things, here's something that I managed to prove:

1. $ p \to ( p \to p ) $ (Axiom 1)
2. $ p \to ( ( p \to p ) \to p ) $ (Axiom 1)
3. $ ( p \to ( ( p \to p ) \to p ) ) \to ( ( p \to ( p \to p ) ) \to ( p \to p ) ) $ (Axiom 2)
4. $ ( p \to ( p \to p ) ) \to ( p \to p ) $ (MP 2, 3)
5. $ p \to p $ (MP 1, 4)

Comment: If you don't have any axioms or inference rules involving $\wedge$ or $\vee$, then or course you won't be able to prove the expected things about them—it is as though your proof system can't tell the difference between $\wedge$ and $\vee$. Meanwhile, yes, some standard proof systems have MP as the only rule of inference, but more axioms are needed.

Comment: Perhaps you need **definitions** of $\vee$ and $\wedge$ in terms of $\to$ and $\lnot$.

Comment: Aren't you just asking about Hilbert style axiomatizations of logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do one of them, $p \to (p \vee q)$.
**Define** $a \vee b$ as $\lnot b \to a$.

We want to prove
$$
p \to (p \vee q) .
$$
This is now merely alternate notation for
$$
p \to (\lnot q \to p) .
$$
But this is an instance of Axiom 1.